# Create React App - specify proxy url for each

Tags: reactjs, proxy, create-react-app

It seems [Create React App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development) only allows me to specify static proxy urls in package.json.

My use case is that I have to test against different servers (local, stage, prod, etc.)

Usually I achieve this by setting an environment (Proxy_URL) before each `npm start`. Then in some js config file I read the env and set the proxy accordingly.

Now that the proxy url is set in package.json with Create React App, I can't think of any way to achieve this. Any suggestion?

BTW, I don't want to `eject`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this may be a future add-on: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1780

The other way to handle this is to change how your API paths work. I worked on a project where we had templates and when you did a build for different environments it would create config files with the API info necessary for each environment. So your API requests would need to build a full URL instead of a relative one and you could get the info from a config template.